# Highlight Tabulator cell which its value is updated

Tags: jquery, tabulator

If have a `Tabulator` table and dynamically update or add new rows to it. I want to highlight the cells in existing rows which their values are changed. Let's say my table object is `myTable`, I wrote below lines:

```
myTable.updateOrAddData(fieldsData).then(function (rows) {
    for (var key in rows[0]['_row']['cells']) {
        if (rows[0]['_row']['cells'].hasOwnProperty(key))
            if (rows[0]['_row']['cells'][key]['oldValue'] != null) {
                // Now get the element of the current cell and apply jQuery highlight to it
            }
    }
});
```

How should I get the cell element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me to access the element of the cell which is changed as the row is updated:

```
myTable.updateOrAddData(row).then(function(rows) {
  try {
    for (var key in rows[0]['_row']['cells']) {
      if (rows[0]['_row']['cells'].hasOwnProperty(key))
        if (typeof rows[0]['_row']['cells'][key]['oldValue'] != 'undefined' && rows[0]['_row']['cells'][key]['oldValue'] != null) {
          var cell = rows[0]['_row'].getCell(rows[0]['_row']['cells'][key]['column']['field']); // specify the column to get the cell of
          $(cell['element']).effect("highlight", {
            color: '#329cff'
         }, 1000); // highlight effect for 1 second
        }
    }
  } catch (e) {}
});
```